# Solana Can't find devnet.json

Tags: windows-10, solana

I'm following [this article](https://dev.to/devindxdeveloper/creating-an-nft-on-solana-with-metaplex-candy-machine-4agp) as a practice.
And stuck with

```
cat .config/solana/devnet.json
```

I realize that windows OS doesn't have `cat` so I tried

```
type ~/.config/solana/devnet.json
```

that result in

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

so I try again with

```
type "~/.config/solana/devnet.json"
```

and this time, it leads to

> The system cannot find the file specified.

It's kind of surprise me so I browse that directory(C:\Users\my-name\.config\solana) and found devnet.json is truly not there.

My questions are where could this file be? Or which step I might do wrong so the file was not generated? I check the result message of each step, things look fine...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out since I didn't change the working directory so the devnet.json is saved in `C:\Windows\System32\~\.config\solana`

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem
It seems that there is no devnet.json file created but the devnet wallet works successfully

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you may download git bash on your windows machine and can simply use `cat` and all bash commands after?

Answer (score 0):

You're following Linux instructions which are not 100% compatible with your Windows OS. ~ is alias for home directory in Linux and it doesn't work in Windows where ~ is a normal char. That led to you the initial confusion. Also other differences like type / cat. On Windows use full path to your home directory (usually something like C:\Users..., etc.). So your key-gen command can look like something like this

```
solana-keygen new --outfile C:/Users/hsiao/keys/devnet.json
```

Then you can use

```
solana config --keypair C:/Users/hsiao/keys/devnet.json
```

and be happy ever after!